# ImportError: No module named env

Tags: python

I am working on Sedona Framework http://www.sedonadev.org

On executing makeunixvm.py python script I am getting below error:

ImportError: No module named env

What is env module? I searched lot but unable to find 'env' module.
I'm getting same error even after installing virtualenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always try `pip` installing it:

```
pip install env
```

You can find more info about the package and what it does [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/env)

Comment: I try this way also... requirement already satisfied. But again import error : no module named env is coming everytime.